# Updating an Android project via CLI to include two downloaded SDK libraries

Tags: android, cordova

I am attempting to add a main expansion file to my Cordova Android project. Before I can go further, I need to link up two libraries with the project. I am stuck on the following instructions in http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#AboutLibraries:

> from a command line, update your project to include the libraries:
>
> Change directories to the /tools/ directory.
>
> Execute android update project with the --library option to add both
>   the LVL and the Downloader Library to your project. For example:

```
android update project --path ~/Android/MyApp \
--library ~/android_sdk/extras/google/market_licensing \
--library ~/android_sdk/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library
```

I formatted the first part to match my system (my best understanding of what to do):

```
android update project --path ~/Documents/AndroidApps/apkext --library ~/Developer/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/market_licensing
```

I got this error message:

```
Error: /Users/Steve/Documents/AndroidApps/apkext is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found).
```

I don't know how to go further. This being a Cordova app, the AndroidManifest.xml file resides in apkext/platforms/android/ and the apk build for the project is in apkext/platforms/android/ant-build

I have already successfully downloaded the two libraries asked for and they are in the tools/ folder in the path indicated. Am I applying the instructions wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're following instructions intended for a native android application and your project is a multiplatform cordova app.

Either you only want to focus on the android platform and don't want to use cordova CLI anymore (so you'll have to install plugins manually or using plugman) or you want to use the CLI and continue with the cordova project.

In the first case, just focus on the paltforms/adroid part of the project and forget all the rest.
paltforms/adroid contains the android native app.
So for example use

```
android update project --path ~/Documents/AndroidApps/apkext/platforms/android --library ~/Developer/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/market_licensing
```

should work better.

In the other case, if you want to keep using the cordova cli, you should build a cordova plugin that would be composed of your libraries, a java class and javascript to call the native code from your cordova app. In that case you just have to configure the plugin to put the libraries in the libs folder.

Anyway, even if you're only interested in android, I think you will have to make a plugin if you want to do something with your libraries?